# How many times will this inner for loop run in this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

```
Algorithm (A)
sum = 0
for i = 1 to n
   for j =1 to i 
   sum = sum+1
```

I have this algorithm and I want to know how many times does the inner for loop run. Is it the summation of (j+1) from j=1 to n?

Comment: "Is it the summation of (j+1) from j=1 to n?" I don't understand this question.

Comment: I meant the loop header actually sorry for not being very clear and thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner loop executions follow the pattern of 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2 which is bounded by O(n<sup>2</sup>). The actual number of executions depends on what your algorithm means when you say `i = 1 to n`. That is, does it end when `i == n` or does it execute until `i` becomes `n+1`.

For more about this particular series, read about the [Triangular Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

Comment: All respect to Dijkstra, but the letters "1 to n" (should) always mean 1, 2, ..., n.

Comment: so the sum=sum+1 statement will execute n(n+1)/2 ? sorry if my question sounds dumb btw

Comment: @Sarah_b: Yes. That is what I meant by "inner loop executions"

Answer (score 1):

It is n*(n+1)/2 times, the sum of the integers from 1 to n. If you have some time, you can read the nice explanation at http://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/

Answer (score 0):

```
Algorithm(A)
sum = 0
for i = 1 to n 
   for j =1 to i   
      sum = sum+1
```

The inner for:

- cycles 1 time  the 1st outer iteration
- cycles 2 times the 2nd outer iteration
- cycles 3 times the 3rd outer iteration
- ...
- cycles n times the nth outer iteration

[image: n*(n+1)/2]

**Links**

1. Info about Big-O notation at [khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-o-notation) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)
2. Info about  and sum of first n numbers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)